# Python: how to create a set of tuples?

Tags: python, set, tuples

I tried making:

```
>>> a = set((0,0))
>>> a
{0}
>>> a.add((0,0))
>>> a
{0, (0,0)}
```

`set.add` works as desired, but can anyone explain why initializing (0,0) is not considered as tuple while creating set?

Also I am looking for functionality (as `set.add` doesn't return the updated set).

```
>>> a = set()
>>> a.union(set(0,0))
{(0,0)}
```

Comment: It *is* considered a tuple. But the `set` constructor takes any *iterable* and adds the items in the iterable to the set.

Comment: Use the set-literal emoji:  `{(0,0)}`

Comment: `a = set([(0,0)])` ?

Comment: Or `a = set(((0, 0),))`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, so constructor and set.add functions differently here ?

Comment: You should try reading the documentation (for example, you can do `help(set)` and `help(set.add)` at the REPL).

Comment: Yes. Constructor takes a sequence of items, `add` takes a single item. The `update` method also takes a sequence, if you should ever need that.

Comment: Yes. Just like the `list` constructor and `list.append`. the most convenient way to make a set like this would be to use the literal notation